# Link between Comparer<T>, IComparer<T> and Comparison<T>

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I'm newbie to C#. I need to write a code which will sort an array of T. I ran into a problem with choosing comparing methods. 
According to my task, I should provide methods, working with  `Comparer<T>`, `IComparer<T>` and `Comparison<T>`. 
I'm looking for a solution, which can bring one method to another, so I avoid repeating the same logic with each of `Comparer<T>`, `IComparer<T>` and `Comparison<T>`.

I know, that `Comparison<T>` may be 'recreated' to `Comparer<T>` with `Comparer<T>.Create`, but how to make `Comparer<T>` and `IComparer<T>` interchangeable?

So far, prototypes of methods look like this.

```
public T[] Sort<T>(T[] toSort) where T : System.IComparable<T>;
    
public T[] Sort<T>(T[] toSort, IComparer<T> comparer);
    
public T[] Sort<T>(T[] toSort, Comparer<T> comparer);
    
public T[] Sort<T>(T[] toSort, Comparison<T> comparison);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how to make `Comparer<T>` and `IComparer<T>` interchangeable?" `Comparer<T>` is *already* implicitly convertible to `IComparer<T>`.

Comment: Sorry, i assume i asked a foolish question. I see, ```IComparer<T>``` is derived from ```Comparer<T>```.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Comparer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.comparer-1?view=net-7.0) implements the `IComparer<T>` interface (in simple terms - it is a `IComparer<T>`):

```cs
public abstract class Comparer<T> : IComparer<T>, IComparer
```

So it can be used anywhere `IComparer<T>` can be used without any effort. I.e. you can just remove `public T[] Sort<T>(T[] toSort, Comparer<T> comparer);` and you still will be able to pass instance of `Comparer<T>` as parameter for `public T[] Sort<T>(T[] toSort, IComparer<T> comparer);`.

Read more:

- [Interfaces - define behavior for multiple types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/interfaces)